# Adding Controls to a panel in Parallel or Concurrent

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

there is panel which I want to add `k` controls to it . I want to specify  task for each of this controls for later use . so :

*UPDATE AT BELOW WITH A SOME OTHER CODES ; Please watch third code ***

```
*****Update*****
    Child Control : PacketData (can be a Button)
    Main Control : panel
    PlaceData() changes the left and top randomly.
```

I had do this :

```
        Parallel.For(0, k, (m) =>
        {
            tasks[m] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {

                PacketData data = new PacketData();
                data.StartTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                lock (data_adding_lock)
                {
                    IAsyncResult iar = panel1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>{
                        PlaceData(ref data);
                        panel1.Controls.Add(data);
                    }));
                    panel1.EndInvoke(iar);
                    while (iar.IsCompleted ==false ) ;
                }


            });
        });
```

It works sometimes nice but sometimes not , for example some times it adds just one `PacketData` to the panel 
Control . Am I loose a race Condition  ?

also I had tried this , but not working...

```
        Parallel.For(0, k, (m) =>
        {
            tasks[m] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                PacketData data;
                lock (data_instancing_lock) {
                 data = new PacketData();}
                data.StartTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                    IAsyncResult iar = panel1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>{
                        PlaceData(ref data);
                        lock(data_adder_lock){
                        panel1.Controls.Add(data);}
                    }));
                    panel1.EndInvoke(iar);


                //PlaceData(ref data);

            });
        });
```

*UPDATE****

here is another example (which is not working...)

```
object l1 = new object();
object l2 = new object();
private delegate void AdderDel(Button bb);
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void AddControl(Button x)
{
    lock (l2)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(x);
    }
}
private void Place(ref Button btn)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int x = rnd.Next(0, this.Width-100);
    int y = rnd.Next(0, this.Height-100);
    btn.Left = x;
    btn.Top = y;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n = 5;
    Task[] t = new Task[n];
    AdderDel ad = new AdderDel(AddControl);
    Parallel.For(0, n, (k) =>
        {

            t[k] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Button b = new Button();

                b.Text = k.ToString();
                b.Height = 50;
                Place(ref b);


                this.BeginInvoke(ad, b);


            });

        });

}
```

Why?

Comment: I fail to see what parallel does here since all threads will converge to a single thread in the BeginInvoke, which cannot execute more than one Add at once.

Comment: What is the way to add them to panel concurrent ?

Comment: You likely don't. For both WinForms and WPF, updating anything in the visual control tree has to be done serially on the UI thread.

Comment: I doubt you can do this concurrently because the updates need to happen on the UI thread. However, you could use the `AddRange` method to quickly add a large number of controls, if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @mike z  : Can I have Parallel Instantiate for a user control ?

Comment: No. UI controls should only be created or modified by the UI thread, and there is only one UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is way too complicated for what it's trying to do, especially since I don't see any advantage in using parallelism here. (Though there might be some reason in your real code, it's hard to tell from your samples.) I think you shouldn't use parallelism until you learn how it works. And programming using a trial-and-error approach should be avoided, because it means you don't actually understand your own code, so it leads to bugs.

But the actual problem in your code doesn't have anything to do with parallelism. It's that you're using `Random` incorrectly. If you use the default constructor, `Random` is seeded with the current time. This means that if you create multiple `Random` instances in short succession, like you do, they are all going to return the same sequence of numbers. This means all the buttons *are* placed on the form, except they are all on the same place, so you see only one of them.

The simplest way to solve this is to have just one instance of `Random` in a field and either access it only from the UI thread, or use a lock when using it.

If you get your code to work, you might consider posting it to [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) to get it reviewed, with some explanation of what you're *actually* trying to do.